# easing an onclick function with element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am new to js and jquery, but I can not figure this out,

lets say i have a div with a id `prev`.

My javascript looks like this:

```
$('#prev').on('click', view.handPrevClick);
```

I animating divs with tween lite(that is what the `handprevclick` function is for), but when u initially click on `prev`, it doesnt animate.

how do I add an animate or time to slow down when on click?

I tried something like this

```
$('#prev').on('click', view.handPrevClick.animate({duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'}));
```

but that's not working?

Comment: the html has an id, not a class !!! its still not working

Comment: I presume you need the function handPrevClick(), it seems you forgot to add the brackets ()

Comment: where are the brackets supposed to be ?

Comment: If you are calling a function, they need to be directly after handPrevClick

Comment: i am getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of undefined

Comment: it looks like this now $('#prev').on('click', view.handPrevClick().animate({duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'}));

Answer (score 0):

if it is a class you need to change your code to:

```
$('.prev').on('click', view.handPrevClick.animate({duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'}));
```

The pound sign -  `'#prev'` you were using before prev is for id's, for classes you use `'.prev'`

Comment: sorry it is right, i just wrote it wrong. I am using an id but the animate doesnt work

Comment: have you got a link to the documentation where handPrevClick is explained? I looked at the tween lite docs but couldn't find this function.

Comment: that is a function i have created, the function is working, but on initial click, the div jumps on the function and then when you click again, there is a transition

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided more of the code you have written in your question.

Comment: i got it working. sorry guys ! it was something i needed to add to the tweenlite